# Wordpress comments with images - disabled by hosting

Tags: wordpress, image, comments, host

My Wordpress websites is stored on a shared host (HostGator).
I noticed that when I insert images into comments, the host returns 413. when I asked the hosting about it, they said that they are limiting the comments size to prevent SQL injection. (I can't even upload a 200kb photo within a comment).
Is there a plugin I can use that by pass it? do you know if this option is disabled in other hosts as well?
I don't want to run my own VPS and this feature is really critical for my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If HostGator set the limit then there is nothing that you can do to change it. I recommend changing hosts.